# Get greater than date when date is in MM dd format

Tags: jquery, mysql, datepicker, date-format

I would like to tell you that I analyzed same questions on stack overflow, but this is bit change.
I want to get greater than date , date is in like "AUGUST 31","SEPTEMBER 15".
Is it feasible or not with this format to use in sql commands.

Comment: It's not really feasible with a date as a string in that format

Comment: Thankyou @Rory McCrossan. :)

I mentioned in the question that I know this is same question but date format is different, don't know why people get negative marking over it.

Comment: Good grief, just store dates as dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly if you use str_to_date and assume all dates are in current year
for example

```
select str_to_date((concat(year(sysdate()),'-','August 17')),'%Y-%M %d');
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date((concat(year(sysdate()),'-','August 17')),'%Y-%M %d') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2017-08-17                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select case when date(now()) > str_to_date((concat(year(sysdate()),'-','August 17')),'%Y-%M %d') then 'Now Gt in date'
    -> else 'Now Lt in date'
    -> end msg;
+----------------+
| msg            |
+----------------+
| Now Gt in date |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```